# packaging python projects failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py, miniconda

I want to package [my python code](https://github.com/oom-ai/oomstore/tree/e527df579e0381b4852a136a96e3a1516cfddf45/sdk/python) and upload it to PyPI so that people can use it easily. I followed the [documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#) for packaging python projects and eventually uploaded it to the [PyPI test website](https://test.pypi.org/project/oomstore/). I ran pip install to try and install it.

Strangely enough, after installing it, I couldn't find the package:

```
(base) ➜  ~ python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/  oomstore==0.0.4
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting oomstore==0.0.4
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/a5/4e7089a1ecb36a59f7f0852a5f96a6054daf886d97132060a7efcda5f04f/oomstore-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Installing collected packages: oomstore
Successfully installed oomstore-0.0.4
(base) ➜  ~ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import oomstore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oomstore'
>>>
```

I went to the installation path of the package and found no python files in it:

```
(base) ➜  ~ cd ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oomstore-0.0.4.dist-info
(base) ➜  oomstore-0.0.4.dist-info ls
INSTALLER     LICENSE       METADATA      RECORD        REQUESTED     WHEEL         top_level.txt
(base) ➜  oomstore-0.0.4.dist-info
```

Did I do something wrong? Is there something wrong with my setup.cfg file? Forgive me for asking such an ignorant question, I'm new to python...

Comment: You appear to be using miniconda which has its own package manager called `conda`.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but the problem of downloading some meta-information files without python files doesn't seem to have anything to do with conda, does it?

Comment: hi john-hen, I've just changed it to `package_dir = oomstore`, and run `python3 -m build` is reporting an error saying it can't parse setup.cfg correctly, so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No, the entry was technically correct: `package_dir` wants a mapping from names to paths, where an empty string is a valid name for the concept of root package (meaning top-level modules not a in package).
The ini format obscures that the left-hand value here is an empty string, because there are no quotes or other delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `package_dir` option is telling setuptools to look inside the `oomstore` directory to find modules and packages, but your `oomstore` package is right there next to setup.cfg.  You should remove the option.

You could also move `oomstore` into an `src` directory and configure `package_dir =\n   = src`; see this articles for reasons to put modules in an `src` directory: https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/